# Postpone the ads script execution

Tags: javascript, php

With the help of the following `php` function:

```
  <?php
  if (!function_exists('wrapAds')) {
    function wrapAds($current_banner_name){
      $STRING_EMPTY = "";
      $openExprResult = array();
      $closeExpreResult = array();
      $openExpr = "/(<div[^>]*>)/";
      $closeExpr = "/(<\/div>)/";

      $banner = tsp_get_banner($current_banner_name);
      $result = '<pre data-script-reference>'
                .htmlspecialchars($banner)
                .'</pre>';

     return $result;
    }
  }
?>
```

I am rendering the following `markup`:

```
<pre data-script-reference="1">&lt;!--- s: middle-box-sidebar --&gt;
&lt;div class="ads middle-box-sidebar"&gt;&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
var FW_type = "4w";
var FW_code = "18xxxx;95xxx;70xxx;0";
var FW_dimension = "300x250";
var FW_category = "gossip";
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src="//optimized-by.4wnetwork.com/simply_loader.js?4wvideo=true" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;!--- e: middle-box-sidebar --&gt;</pre>
```

Now I am tring to postpone the encoded script execution later with the following script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('pre[data-script-reference]'))
   .forEach(function(item){
         var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
         txt.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
         var parentNode = item.parentNode;
         var p0 = txt.innerText;
        //  parentNode.removeChild(item);
         parentNode.innerHTML += p0;

    </script>
```

seems that decoded script isn't executed at all, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a trillion of useless code executions, I just noted a curious statement inside a long list of warnings:
*"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."*. I googled around this message and I found a [*nice question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399721/asynchronously-loaded-external-script-error).

The only *not accepted* answer suggest [**postscribe.js**](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

> ---
>
> ***Asynchronously write javascript, even with document.write.***
>
> ---
>
> Remote scripts, especially ads, block the page from doing anything
>   else while they load. They contribute a large % to load times which
>   affects your bottom line. Asynchronous ads do not block the page and
>   can be delivered after core content - Async FTW.
>
> Why is it so hard to deliver ads asynchronously? Because they may
>   contain calls to document.write, which expects to be handled
>   synchronously. PostScribe lets you deliver a synchronous ad
>   asynchronously without modifying the ad code.

So, since I have to manage both *ads* in the body and in the sidebar, I made a little refactoring, moving the **php** function in the *functions.php*:

```
/**
* redefine and get the legacy ads block from base library by name
* render as encoded plain text inside a *pre* wrapper
*/
function tsp_get_banner($current_banner_name){
  $STRING_EMPTY = "";
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags
  $openExpr = "/(<div[^>]*>)/";
  $closeExpr = "/(<\/div>)/";
  $openExprResult = $closeExpreResult = array();
  $banner = original_tsp_get_banner($current_banner_name);
  preg_match($openExpr, $banner, $openExprResult);
  $banner = preg_replace($openExpr, $STRING_EMPTY, $banner);
  preg_match($closeExpr, $banner, $closeExpreResult);
  $banner = preg_replace($closeExpr, $STRING_EMPTY, $banner);
  return wrapAdsSnippet($banner, $openExprResult[0], $closeExpreResult[0]);
}

function wrapAdsSnippet($source, $prefix, $postfix){
  $result = '<pre data-script-reference style="display:none;">'
                            .htmlspecialchars($source)
                        .'</pre>';
  if(isset($prefix) && isset($postfix)){
        $result = $prefix.$result.$postfix;
    }
  return $result;
}
```

<strike>then I changed the inclusion of the block:</strike>
so that I don't need to change anything.

```
<?php
```

<strike>echo tsp_get_banner("middle-box-sidebar");</strike>

```
  echo renderAds("middle-box-sidebar");
?>
```

I have just to change the final script to include in the **footer.php**:

```
var MyCompanyLab;
(function (MyCompanyLab) {
    "use strict";
    var Ads;
    (function (Ads) {
        var Optimization;
        (function (Optimization) {
            var PostProcessor = (function () {
                function PostProcessor() {
                }
                PostProcessor.postponeAdsExecution = function () {
                    $("pre[data-script-reference]").each(function (idx, item) {
                        var parentNode = item.parentNode;
                        postscribe(parentNode, $('<textarea />').html(item.innerHTML).text(), {
                            done: function () { },
                            error: function () { },
                            releaseAsync: true,
                        });
                        parentNode.removeChild(item);
                    });
                };
                return PostProcessor;
            }());
            Optimization.PostProcessor = PostProcessor;
        })(Optimization = Ads.Optimization || (Ads.Optimization = {}));
    })(Ads = MyCompanyLab.Ads || (MyCompanyLab.Ads = {}));
})(MyCompanyLab|| (MyCompanyLab= {}));


<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  MyCompanyLab.Ads.Optimization.PostProcessor.postponeAdsExecution();
  ...
</script>
```